# how to invoke Receive payment event in quickbooks sdk?

Tags: c#

Invoke the Receive payment and sales Rep event using quickbooks software development kit using c# language in asp.net.

Comment: any efforts made yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Intuit.Ipp libraries:

/* payment.CustomerRef: The Customer reference: Get the customer information from your quickbooks online account  if you don't have one on there create a new one

qbCustomerId seen below is referred to as nameId on QB 
Ex. https://sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/app/customerdetail?nameId=28 is the detail page url for my customer with id = 28.

CustomerName : the name of your customer. could be anything for the request

invoice QuickBooksId: The Id for the invoice you're receiving the payment for.

Ex. https://sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/app/invoice?txnId=277 is the detail page url for an invoice on my QB account. In this case the id is 277

Insert is the quickbooks online method you will call to add the payment. same way you would add any quickbooks online entity for that matter.
 */

```
            var payment = new Payment ();  //Quickbooks Payment Entity                
            payment.CustomerRef = new ReferenceType()
            {
                type = Enum.GetName(typeof(objectNameEnumType), objectNameEnumType.Customer),
                Value = "<qbCustomerId>",
                name = "<CustomerName>"
            };

            var linkedTxn = new List<LinkedTxn>
            {
                new LinkedTxn
                {
                    TxnId = "<invoice QuickBooksId>",
                    TxnType = objectNameEnumType.Invoice.ToString(),
                }
            };
            var line = new List<Line>
            {
                new Line
                {
                    Amount = amount,
                    LinkedTxn = linkedTxn.ToArray(),
                    AmountSpecified = true                                      
                }
            };
            payment.Line = line.ToArray();
            payment.TotalAmt = amount;
            payment.TotalAmtSpecified = true;
            var result = Insert(payment);
```